# MAGENTO 2 Checkout javascript not showing shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, jquery, onestepcheckout

i have a problem in the checkout with the Magento 2.1.6 version.

In the second step only the cart resume is showed and i have this error in the console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at jQuery.fn.init.init (jquery.min.js:2)
at new jQuery.fn.init (/pub/static/version1508932666/frontend/Soul/equiva/es_ES/jquery/jquery-migrate.js:225)
at jQuery.fn.init.p [as constructor] (jquery.min.js:2)
at jQuery.fn.init.pushStack (jquery.min.js:2)
at jQuery.fn.init.before (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.wrapNode (/pub/static/version1508932666/frontend/Soul/equiva/es_ES/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/renderer.js:292)
at node (/pub/static/version1508932666/frontend/Soul/equiva/es_ES/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/renderer.js:334)
at /pub/static/version1508932666/frontend/Soul/equiva/es_ES/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/renderer.js:222
at Array.some (<anonymous>)
at /pub/static/version1508932666/frontend/Soul/equiva/es_ES/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/renderer.js:21
```

The only change was on pass from the development server to production one.